Batch file acting wierd
@echo off
title create backup of currently open folder windows
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

powershell  @^(^(New-Object -com shell.application^).Windows^(^)^).Document.Folder.Self.Path >> prevfolderpaths.txt

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN (prevfolderpaths.txt) DO (

set "var=%%f"
set "firstletters=!var:~0,2!"

IF "!firstletters!" == "::" ( ECHO start shell:%%~f >> foldersession.bat) ELSE ( ECHO start "" "%%~f" >> foldersession.bat)

)

del "prevfolderpaths.txt"

I am using the following as a backup for all open folder when windows crashes when i click on it it from explorer it works well, it creates a batch file like this that i can open after
foldersession.bat
start "" "C:\Users\sscic\Downloads"  
start "" "C:\Windows\symbolic links\New folder" 
start "" "C:\Users\sscic\Downloads" 

Works well when i open it by clicking it, the problem is i tried to set it via task scheduler so I can back it every few minutes but doesnt work, it creates no foldersession
I also tried launching it via explorer.exe C:\Users\sscic\explorer.exe "C:\Windows\symbolic links\New folder\foldersave.bat"
to no avail its baffling me completely any pros here have an idea?
No foldersession.bat created when automating task

it was the start in folder the issue in taks scheduler thanks for the reply

The code you have submitted is what I call lazy. It uses output files with relative paths, yet it does not define the location from which they are relative. When you run something from Task Scheduler, within the configuration settings for the task, you can input the location of the 'Start in' directory, which will become the current working directory for your script on opening.
Usually when you don't define the current directory, or configure the Start in location, the default will become C:\Windows\System32, and my best guess is that is your problem.
Also, as this is a programming site, not a software configuration one, your code could be rewrote to be more efficient, require no intermediate output file, and be done in just a single line.
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "@((New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application).Windows()).Document.Folder.Self.Path | ForEach-Object {If ($_.StartsWith('::')) {Write-Output \"@Start Shell:$_\"} Else {Write-Output \"@Start `\"`\" `\"$_`\"\"}} | Out-File '.\FolderSession.cmd' -Encoding OEM"

In the code above I changed your .bat file extension to .cmd, because that is the proper extension for batch files created this century.

it was the start in folder the issue in taks scheduler thanks for the reply – I also updated the code

If my answer helped solve your problem, please consider an action based upon the content of What should I do when someone answers my question?.
